# Removing all numbers from a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string that I need to remove all numerical values from. So for example

```
H1 --> H
Thi2341s i34s a876 57834tes9873t --> This is a test
```

And so forth...

I tried this method...

```
NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@""];
```

... though it didn't successfully remove the numbers from the string. I am guessing that @"[^0-9]" isn't a valid occurrence. Any ideas of how I can achieve this without copying the method ten times for each digit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to indicate that a regular expression search should be used:

```
NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

And note the regular expression needs to be `[0-9]`, not `[^0-9]`. What you have says "any character except the digits 0-9".

Answer (score 1):

Instead use:

[– replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a)

For example:

```
NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"a123xy45678z"];
[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[0-9]+"
                          withString:@""
                             options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
```